# .Except<T> is throwing an Exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have the following code:

```
Public Shared Function GetAvailableManufacturers() As List(Of Manufacturer)
    'first get all the live orders and extract their mfrs'
    Dim sos As List(Of OrderForm) = GetFormsByStatus(StockStatus.Building)
    Dim unavailableMfrs As New List(Of Manufacturer)
    For Each so As StockingOrder In sos
        unavailableMfrs.Add(so.Source)
    Next

    'then remove all mfrs with an open SO from a list of all mfrs'
    Dim allMfrs As List(Of Manufacturer) = Manufacturer.GetManufacturers
    Return allMfrs.Except(unavailableMfrs) <----- error here
End Function
```

Explanation of what the above does:

- `GetFormsByStatus()` self-explanatory
- `GetManufacturers()` returns a list of all manufacturers in the database

My idea to get available manufacturers was to get a list of all the manufacturers in my open forms, then get a list of all manufacturers and exclude all the manufacturers in the first list, illustrated like so (pseudo):

```
List A: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
List B: {5,7,10}
Result: {1,2,3,4,6,8,9}
```

I have set up my `Manufacturer` class according to [this article](http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/loving-linq-generics-using-except-with-equalitycomparert) so that it can be compared, but I'm still getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type '`<ExceptIterator>d__92'1[csCore.Manufacturer]'` to type '`System.Collections.Generic.List'1[csCore.Manufacturer]`'.

I thought at first that because during testing `GetFormsByStatus()` returns 0 results maybe that was causing problems, but it doesn't make sense that `Except()` wouldn't work if the provided list had 0 items. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function expects a List(Of Manufacturer) return type, not an IEnumerable(Of Manufacturer), so adding a .ToList() to the return value should fix it:

```
Return allMfrs.Except(unavailableMfrs).ToList()
```

Comment: True, but I really think the opposite approach is better: Make the method return an `IEnumerable(of Manufacturer)` instead, let the caller decide whether or not to spend the extra resources materializing it into a list.  In fact, very rarely should *any* method actually return a mutable collection.

Comment: @aaronaught - truth. this answer is still the correct answer for the question, but you are absolutely right. my actual implementation reflects this.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is declared as returning List(Of Manufacturer), but your Return statement is returning only an IEnumerable(Of Manufacturer).  Change the return statement to:

```
Return allMfrs.Except(unavailableMfrs).ToList()
```

If you turn Option Strict On, I believe VB will catch this kind of error at compile time, instead of blowing up at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) returns `IEnumerable<T>`, but your return type is `List(Of T)`.

Change your last line to:

```
Return allMfrs.Except(unavailableMfrs).ToList()
```